Apache Airflow for IoT device simulators
I want to use Apache Airflow for IoT device simulator written in python. Let's say I want to run that script for 25000 devices and the 25000 invocations should run concurrently. Is apache airflow is right tool to be used or there are other opensource tools which will be good fit in this use case?
